# I'm searching for the name of a zombie movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

It is a zombie movie in which a group of people are doing a road trip in a van. They stop at a western village. At a certain point, a man in the group gets bitten and ask the others to leave him before he attacks them. The main actor is a woman left alone at the end.

I bet my friend I could find this movie, but it turns out being more complicated than I thought. The movie is probably from the 1990s/2000s, since my friend watched it a while ago.

It was like spreading a virus before turning into zombies. They got fevers then the face turned white.

It was a scary movie, not a funny one.

Comment: You've got a good start. Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to see what other information you can [edit] in. Like, when was "a while ago" that you watched it? Was it in English? Did it look like it had been redubbed? Did you watch it in theaters? On TV? On VHS/DVD? YouTube?

Comment: There are so many zombie movies that any additional details, even ones that may seem trivial to you, might help to identify the film you seek. Please try to add anything that may be distinctive,

Answer (score 1):

There a chance this movie is Resident Evil Extinction?

There is a virus that turns people into zombies- don't recall anyone's face changing colour.

It came out past 2000, and it at least *tried* to be scary.

Road trip in a van- sort of, there *are* humans driving across the Nevada wasteland, but I think it's in a bus. They *do* stop at a small town at the beginning- only it turns out to be overrun with zombies and IIRC at least one of them gets bitten and infected.

Woman left alone at the end- could be Alice, the main heroine of the series, played by Milla Jovovich.

Comment: not really a road trip and it is a convoy not a single van.

Comment: Nice try, but it is not that one. Thanks a lot for trying anyway !